# SQL Server : group entries by start and end event

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

Unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience with SQL Server.

I have a table with the following structure and sample data:

| ID | Status | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 68 | 2 | 10.01.2022 08:45:02 |
| 52 | 0 | 10.01.2022 08:44:29 |
| 50 | 0 | 10.01.2022 08:41:12 |
| 46 | 0 | 10.01.2022 08:41:02 |
| 40 | 1 | 10.01.2022 08:40:07 |
| 38 | 2 | 10.01.2022 08:20:05 |
| 32 | 0 | 10.01.2022 08:19:29 |
| 30 | 1 | 10.01.2022 08:15:34 |

What I have to do now is the timestamp where the status 1 is as start, the timestamp of status 2 as the end and count the entries with 0 in between. Unfortunately the entries are not consecutive. So I can't just count the ID forwards or backwards. The result should look like this:

| Start | End | CountStatus0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10.01.2022 08:40:07 | 10.01.2022 08:45:02 | 3 |
| 10.01.2022 08:15:34 | 10.01.2022 08:20:05 | 1 |

I would be very grateful for a suggestion on how to best solve this.
I already tried to solve it with the `group by` function but I had no success yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've tagged SQL Server 2008 - I believe the following is compatible, of course unable to test.

You can use a lateral join (*cross apply*) to find the corresponding *end* timestamp that applies to each row.

Then simply aggregate by the end timestamp and count rows where the status is zero.

```
with e as (
    select t.timestamp tstart, e.timestamp tend
    from t
    cross apply (
        select Min(timestamp) timestamp
        from t t2
        where t2.status=2
        and t2.timestamp > t.timestamp
    )e
    where status=0
)

select Min(tstart) [Start], Max(tend) [end], count(*) CountStatus0
from e
group by tend
order by [start] desc
```

See [example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=003c3cd7e4ff724e8f1773c74f2b5079)